# How to query by ObjectId in Motor in tornado

Tags: python, mongodb, objectid, tornado-motor

I am trying to use tornado, and my use case is to query by the object ID.

I have seen examples and ref's to query by anything else, but the ObjectID. since it is unique, I want to use it instead to query.

Any suggestions how to use the ObjectId for querying using motor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Import [`ObjectId`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.7/api/pymongo/objectid.html) from `bson`:

```
import motor
from bson import ObjectId

cursor = collection.find({ "_id": ObjectId('54b89db31d41c8159742d65a') })
```